# python - Issue with nested print statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have recently begun programming with python 3 and am trying to build a bot (WIP). But when I run and get to line 15 which is "print("cut the 2nd wire") by responding W, 3, N. The program just ends and doesn't execute the line of code.

```
def logic():  # this is the logic for the menu
    selection = input("What module do you want to defuse? [W]ires :")
    if selection.upper() == "W":
        wires()


def wires():  # this is the logic for wires
    numwires = int(input("How many wires do you have? : "))
    if numwires == 3:
        question1 = input("are there red wires: Y/N:")
        if question1.upper() == "Y":
            # next question here
            if question1.upper() == "N":
                print("cut the 2nd wire")


logic()
```

this is what the terminal shows

```
What module do you want to defuse? [W]ires :w
How many wires do you have? : 3
are there red wires: Y/N:n

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong and why the print statement does not work.

Comment: You first check if a string equals "Y", then you check if **the same string** equals "N". This is never true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have the check for if the answer was "N" inside the if statement for if it is "Y". Your code currently checks if the answer is "Y", and then it checks if the answer is "N". It can never be both, meaning the print statement is never triggered.

To fix this, move the following two lines back by one indent:

```
            if question1.upper() == "N":
                print("cut the 2nd wire")
```

The function should look like this:

```
def wires():  # this is the logic for wires
    numwires = int(input("How many wires do you have? : "))
    if numwires == 3:
        question1 = input("are there red wires: Y/N:")
        if question1.upper() == "Y":
            # next question here
            pass  # Empty if statement, so you need the keyword 'pass'
        if question1.upper() == "N":
            print("cut the 2nd wire")
```

Comment: I made that change but i got an error saying ```IndentationError: expected an indented block after 'if' statement on line 12```

Answer (score 3):

Your indentation is off:

```
def wires():  # this is the logic for wires
    numwires = int(input("How many wires do you have? : "))
    if numwires == 3:
        question1 = input("are there red wires: Y/N:")
        if question1.upper() == "Y":
            # next question here
        elif question1.upper() == "N":
            print("cut the 2nd wire")
```

You don't need to use `elif` here but I've made the change

Comment: I changed that but then I got an error saying ```IndentationError: expected an indented block after 'if' statement on line 12```

Comment: You need the `elif` if the `if` block can change `question1` to N and you don't want this change to trigger what's in the `elif` block